# Launching Swing application with install4j on windows10 looks blurry

Tags: java, install4j

I have a swing application that looks blurry on Windows 10 when launched with an install4j launcher. When I start the same application using the same JRE with a .bat file the blurriness goes away. I think it has something to do with DPI or compatibility, but I don't see any settings in install4j version 6 to control this. The bat file is using javaw.

This post may have some insight.
https://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since install4j 7, the installer will be DPI-aware if the minimum Java version of the project is 9. Java 1.8 and lower do not have sufficient high DPI support in Swing.

For install4j 6.x, only up-scaling is supported.